# How can I programmatically see what resources are using ssl certificates?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-load-balancer

I'm working through this issue: [GCP API for getting list of load balancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50814300/gcp-api-for-getting-list-of-load-balancer)

There is no "list load balancers" API call so I'm trying to do this programmatically.

In the web console I can click on a "load balancer" and see what cert it is using under "Frontend". If I follow the link to the cert I get a separate "Certificate details" page that includes an "In use by" field.

The APIs for listing URL Maps and [sslCertificates](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/sslCertificates/aggregatedList) do not include this linkage.

How is the web console collecting URL Maps with their certs? The convoluted dependency chain of all these little components is unclear to me.

## EDIT

It looks like I have to use the target proxy to link the two? Just looking at how terraform connects things:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_managed_ssl_certificate

Answer (score 3):

The Google Cloud Console will not show what SSL certificates were being used by Load Balancers. Moreover, for your question regarding how the console collects URL Maps with their certificate, you can try the commands below on Google Cloud CLI.

Display the list of URL maps :

```
gcloud compute url-maps list
```

Display the information about a single URL map :

```
gcloud compute url-maps describe URL_MAP_NAME
```

Comment: "for your question regarding how the console collects URL Maps with their certificate...". My question was about the other direction. In the UI the "Certificate details" page includes an "In use by" field which is not available via the API. In the UI I can go to the "load balancing components view" page > "certificates" tab > click on a cert and see its "In use by" field. How is the UI doing that? I doubt its iterating over ALL url maps on the fly, does it have its own cache/DB? This sort of thing is what makes GCP LBs very opaque and frustrating to work with. Thanks!